# solr search with spaces not working properly

Tags: php, solr

I'm using solr to search my data, and I used to search with the query like

```
title:*something here*
```

And it is working fine without spaces. But if I search like

```
seva sa
```

Even I have below

```
seva samithi
```

It is searching with either "seva" or "sa". Can anyone suggest me to do a proper way to search in solr.

Comment: Are you searching with wildcards?

Comment: No, I'm searching with the complete word as single word only

Comment: So you're searching `title:"seva samithi"`, or are you search `title:seva samithi` or `title:*sema samithi*`? All these will be parsed differently and means different things.

Comment: Im using title:*sema sa*

Answer (score 1):

You're performing a wildcard search. Wildcard searches are not analyzed, so they bypass the regular analysis chain - the only thing that will match "*sema sa*" is a single token that contain the whole string in the exact case. That would probably be either a StrField or a field indexed with a KeywordTokenizer instead of the regular tokenizer.

A better solution if you want to match any content within one of the words might be to use a ngramfilter, so that each token gets indexed in its shorter forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use (seva sa) assuming you have OR some default operator

Answer (score 0):

Try these tutorial

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

From what I saw from your query you are using a wild card, there are ways to search on solr because by default it uses a fuzzy system to search that is why it is ending up the result you are posting.